# RequestDispatcher forward to jsp being caught by servlet url pattern

Tags: jsp, servlets, web.xml, url-mapping

I have a jsp located in the `/package` directory.

Then I map my servlet with a WebServlet Annotation of `"/package/*"`.

In my servlet, I forward the request to a jsp in the above directory:

```
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = 
                request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/package/some_file.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

This causes a StackOverflowError:

> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke
>   Servlet.service() for servlet SomeServlet threw exception

I can easily fix this by changing the name of the jsp folder to something else (eg: `package_files`). But I don't understand why this is necessary because I thought the servlets and the jsp folders were in entirely different locations (specifically, the servlet is in `/web/WEB-INF/classes/package` while the jsp is in `/web/package`.

Am I mistaken, or is there something wrong with my setup?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you saying that you expected that `@WebServlet("/package/*")` is referring to `/web/WEB-INF/classes/package`? Where exactly did you learn that? The official tutorial and documentation just say that `@WebServlet` value represents the web path (URL pattern) not the class path (file system location).

Comment: I see, so is it recommended not to have URL patterns and root folders be of the same name?

Comment: ...because then you cannot match servlets with a wildcard at the end without also matching the contents of the folder in the root directory.